# simple xml editor using javascript and msxml

Tags: javascript, xml

whether there is an example of such an implementation?
howto load/save context of msxml to/from edit or text control?

```
<html><head>
<script language="JavaScript">
function loadxml()
{
  var fileName = document.getElementById("fileName");

  var xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
  xmlData.load(fileName.value);

  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  editor.value = xmlData; // got [object]
}
function testxml()
{
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
  // editor.value load by msxml
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="fileName"/>
<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadxml();"/>
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="testxml();"/><br>
<textarea id="editor" rows="25" cols="50">no data</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
editor.value = xmlData.xml
```

And vice-versa only use loadXML instead of load method on ActiveX object

```
 var xmlData = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument");
 xmlData.loadXML( editor.value );
```

see for ex. http://joncom.be/code/javascript-xml-conversion/

PS Originally misunderstood question, so there are irrelevant comments now

Comment: I can using activex. Yes, it's IE only.

Comment: So the answer still works. Due to security reasons, you cannot access to file protocol from JavaScript if page is from other protocol - workaraound is to use Flash or Java file loader ( not JavaScript )

Comment: I do not work with files, only with activex objects. Have you tried my example? i can load file save it to other place.. i need to load context of msxml to editbox